# Find lines by pattern, leave only pattern but leave unmatched lines as they are

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, pipeline

So there is an input file res.txt like this

```
processing file 0x8001.values
channel 1: 123
channel 2: 234
channel 3: 345
processing file 0x8002.values
channel 1: 456
channel 2: 567
channel 3: 678
```

I have a pattern like this

```
0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

Using, for example,

```
grep -o "0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]" res.txt
```

I can get the list of my filenames (without .values) which is fine!

```
0x8001
0x8002
```

But want still all the other lines, which did not match the pattern to stay where they are like this:

```
0x8001
channel 1: 123
channel 2: 234
channel 3: 345
0x8002
channel 1: 456
channel 2: 567
channel 3: 678
```

I am quite familiar with sed but I could not find a way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed.

```
$ sed 's/.*\(0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\).*/\1/' file
0x8001
channel 1: 123
channel 2: 234
channel 3: 345
0x8002
channel 1: 456
channel 2: 567
channel 3: 678
```

I assumed that there is only one hexadecimal string like `0x8001` present in a line.

Comment: Wow, man. I have been fighting with this \(\) and \1 feature of sed for like 2 hours but was always getting
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
But your version works. Hmm.

Comment: because basic sed use BRE. In BRE, you need to use `\(..\)` to represent a capturing group. Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: In my version of sed  
`-r, --regexp-extended`  
`echo "Processing analyseThresholds.C("values/0x861c.values",1)..." | sed -r 's/.*\(0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\).*/\1/'`  
`sed: -e expression #1, char 48: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`  
`echo "Processing analyseThresholds.C("values/0x861c.values",1)..." | sed    's/.*\(0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\).*/\1/'`  
`0x861c`

Comment: if you use `-r` then you don't need to escape the brackets. `sed -r 's/.*(0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]).*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk you can [use `match` function](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) like this with your regex:

```
awk 'match($0, /0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/){$0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} 1' file
0x8001
channel 1: 123
channel 2: 234
channel 3: 345
0x8002
channel 1: 456
channel 2: 567
channel 3: 678
```